# windows phone 8 Emulator Invalid pointer Error

Tags: windows-phone-8, parallels

```
The Windows Phone Emulator wasn't able to create virtual machine:

Couldn't change Processor of the virtual machine: 'Emulator WVGA 512.User' failed to modify device 'Processor'. (virtual machine ID XXX)

Cannot assign the specified number of processor for virtual machine 'Emulator WVGA 512.user' is out of range. The range is 1 through 1 ( virtual machine ID XXX)
```

I got this message when running the Emulator

I am using my Windows 8 on mac os  with Parallels Desktop 8 for Mac

I did nested virtual machine ,, 
I did enable the hypervisor but it does solve the problem..

Any suggestions ??

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [solution](http://kb.parallels.com/en/115211) to my problem was to change the CPU number from 1 to 2.

1. Shut down Windows 8 on Parallels Desktop 8.
2. From Parallels > Configure menu > General tab > CPU : 2

Comment: This approach works, but I've had constant issues. Mostly that the Hyper-V VMs would get deleted and the Visual Studio wouldn't recreate them (usually saying it couldn't set the number of CPUs).

Instead, I allocated 2 CPUs to the **Windows 8** VM (Parallels > Virtual Machine > Configure > General) and haven't had an issue since (*fingers crossed*)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution here is that you change the virtual processors count to 1 on the **Hyper-V Manager**. Windows Phone 8 Emulator is configured for dual core processors, but it does also run on single core. And it is even more stable than it's dual core configuration in virtual environments.

This is the official Parallels knowledge base post: [KB Parallels - 115211](http://kb.parallels.com/en/115211)